# How to change the color of hyperlinks in dark themed Eclipse on a Mac?

Tags: eclipse, ide, themes

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with the dark Moonrise theme on OS X Yosemite. All hyperlinks that appear in the preferences are dark blue and unreadable:

[image: Unreadable links]

I tried to modify them on `Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts` but it seems to take no effect:

[image: Custom colors not taking effect]

Here's everything I have installed:

[image: Installed plugins]

Anything I could be missing?

Comment: I believe this UI part is using the OS theme for hyperlink color.. so try changing your OS color if you can

Comment: @flafoux I don't believe Mac OS lets you define hyperlink colors.  We may be stuck just lightening our interfaces.